# Postgres Sequence Value Not Incrementing After Inserting Records

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TBL_CACL;
CREATE TABLE TBL_CACL (
   ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   NAME VARCHAR(250)  UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

I am able to query postgres likes this:

```
SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
```

to determine that the default name for the sequence on the table is tbl_cacl_id_seq

I can then read its nextVal like this:

```
SELECT nextval('tbl_cacl_id_seq');
```

Directly after creating the table the value is '1'

However, if I insert several rows of data like this:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_CACL
VALUES
(1, 'CACL_123'),
(2, 'CACL_234'),
(3, 'CACL_345');
```

and I read nextVal for the table, it returns '2'

I would have thought that tbl_cacl_id_seq would be '4'. Clearly I misunderstanding how the insert is related to the nextVal. Why is the sequence out of sync with the inserts and how do I get them in sequence? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tbl_cacl_id_seq` gets incremented only when the function `nextval('tbl_cacl_id_seq')` is called. This function call will not happen since you have provided values for ID column during insert (hence no need to get the default value).

Comment: Exactly. If you use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`, it will become clear what is going on.

Comment: Brilliant!. I get it now. Thanks!